# A problem on Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

> If $T_1$ and $T_2$ denote the trapezoidal approximations to $I=\int_a^b f(x)dx$ with one and two intervals respectively, then show that $$I=T_2+1/3(T_2-T_1)$$

I don't know how to solve. I know trapezoidal rule but here unable to start. What is $T_1$ and etc. Please help.

Edit:

I start with $T_1=\frac{b-a}{2}(f(a)+f(b))$ and $T_2=\frac{h}{2}(f(a)+2f(a+h)+f(b))$ where $h=(b-a)/2$.

If it is correct, then how to get the result?

Comment: $T_1$ is defined in the question and "etc" as well. Spend some effort.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have written it. please guide me next.

Comment: @user1942348 As stated, the question is false. Are you sure that the left side ought to be $I$?

Comment: You can now express $I$ as a combination of the $f(\cdot)$. But the question doesn't say what $I$ is in the equation !

Comment: With your notation, $I$ becomes the Simpson rule approximation (with one panel). Please check whether that is perhaps what you have to show.

Comment: As mentioned, this is false. Presumably, at some earlier point, you were given a form for $f$, like $f(x)=ax+b$ or something like that.

Comment: I is given only as $I=\int_a^b f(x)dx$. Question is written here correctly. I don't know whrther it is not correct in book.

Comment: The last equation indeed achieves Simpson's rule, but this is nowhere said. Did you copy the whole question ?

Comment: yes i have copied correctly.

Comment: Hem, is there nothing said about Simpson's rue or about $f$ in the neighborhood ? Otherwise I'll vote to close the post as lacking context.

Comment: Not Simpson, rather  trapezoidal approximations. Nothing more is given.

Comment: Are you told something about $f(x)$, such that it is a polynomial of degree $\le 3$?